# How to pull out the name of the primary key column(s) of a MS SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, primary-key, insert-update

I have a MS SQL Server Database with about 75 tables on it, and I am trying to insert records into tables if a record with the same primary key doesn't exist, or update if they do.
I could hard code the primary keys for every table into my vb.net code, but I'd rather not as more tables are to be added at a later date and my code needs to handle this without being changed. Is there a way to pull out the primary key column name(s) from a table using a query so I can loop through each table executing the same code?

Thanks,
Tom

P.S. I am a bit of a newbie when it comes to SQL so if you have the time please be simple and clear with any responses.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at  [Find Tables With Primary Key Constraint in Database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/04/sql-server-2005-find-tables-with-primary-key-constraint-in-database/)

```
SELECT  i.name AS IndexName,
        OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
        COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id) AS ColumnName
FROM    sys.indexes AS i INNER JOIN 
        sys.index_columns AS ic ON  i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
                                AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE   i.is_primary_key = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way of doing this. It is called [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27y4ybxw(v=VS.100).aspx) :)

Basically, you need a `DataAdapter` to fetch the data from your DB to a `DataSet`. You then add, modify or remove rows to a `DataTable` in the `DataSet` and when you're ready to commit to the DB you tell `DataAdapter` to do so. The `DataSet` can keep track of the changes made to it and the `DataAdapter` knows what statement to use depending on the `RowState` property of a row/record.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254937.aspx) how to retrieve and modify data using ADO.NET.